# How to connect two vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm having trouble creating a new face to this model, just wondering if anybody is able to help me connecting the two vertices highlighted in this image?
[image]

Comment: Select both of them and press J key.

Comment: @joshsanfelici that worked! thank you so much!

Comment: Try also K (Knife) tool.